# War File with Webservice is not deployed in JBOSS EAP 6.2 in Standalone server

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I tried to build a war file which contains web servicesm which deploys in JBOSS AS 5 and 6 without any issues.

But, in JBOSS EAP (Standalone) it gave me the following error.

I dont have any clue where to look for the error message.

```
18:20:56,236 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start
service jboss.deployment.unit."service.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service j
boss.deployment.unit."service.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "s
ervice.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseServic
e.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.
java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746
) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1
.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1
.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resourc
e-adapter-name-service not found
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:4
48) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefau
ltResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:270)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processM
essageBeans(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:152)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processA
nnotations(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:80)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitPro
cessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:58)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDe
ploymentUnitProcessor.java:81)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseServic
e.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        ... 5 more

18:20:56,245 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of d
eployment "service.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"service.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.s
ervice.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"service.war\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to
process phase PARSE of deployment \"service.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-res
ource-adapter-name-service not found"}}
18:20:59,072 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped dep
loyment service.war (runtime-name: service.war) in 2827ms
```

What is wrong with my deployment or with my application.

Its CXF, Hibernate, Spring and MY SQL jar file.

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the MDB resource to the EJB subsystem. The following needs to be added to the EJB3 subsystem in your XML configuration. There might be a way in CLI or the web console as well.

```xml
 <mdb>  
      <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="hornetq-ra"/>  
      <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>  
 </mdb>
```

Comment: Thank you James, But, how did you know this. Is this documented any where and whats the relation between this configuration and error. Please explain.

Comment: TBH I see some references in the EAP 6 documentation around this, but I found the actual answer on the JBoss Community forums.